# Problem with \appendix, want one main "Appendix" and then Appendix A, B, C etc

Tags: appendices

I have some problem using `\appendix`. I want one main "Appendix" page with a "table of content for the appendixes" and after that all the appendixes (by themselves) starting at the top of a new page. See picture made in paint, page brake illustrated by a line. Hope this i'sent to much asked. J

[image]

My code is now:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% APPENDIX
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\appendix
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Appendix A
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Appendix A}
\section{Numerical results}\label{app:AppendixA}

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty} \cleardoublepage %\pagestyle{fancyplain}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Appendix B
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter{Appendix B}
\section{Figures}\label{app:AppendixB}

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty} \cleardoublepage %\pagestyle{fancyplain}
```

Comment: This can be achieved with any package that allow partial table of contents, `etoc, tableof, titletoc,minitoc` we need to know the class you use.

Comment: I'm using \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}. The answer below did the trick! J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is two solutions.

With [tableof](http://ctan.org/pkg/tableof) package

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tableof}
\AtBeginDocument{\tofOpenTocFileForWrite}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents % just to display the heading Contents
\tableof{}%  replace \tableofcontents i.e. display toc file
\chapter{First}
\section{Foo}

\appendix
\tableofcontents
\tableof{appendix}
\toftagstart{appendix}
\chapter{First appendix}
\section{Foo appendix}

\chapter{Last Appendix}
\section{Barappendix}
\toftagstop{appendix}
\end{document}
```

With [titletoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\section{Foo}

\appendix
\startcontents
\printcontents{}{0}{%
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}%
\tableofcontents}
\chapter{First appendix}
\section{Foo appendix}

\chapter{Last Appendix}
\section{Bar appendix}
\stopcontents
\end{document}
```

Comment: The last one works perfect! Did some adding; e.g. put the table of content for Appendix in the main table of content using \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix} after \appendix. Exactly what i wanted!  Big thanks!